# What is the proper way to install an application with the Python packet manager (pip)?

Tags: python, pip

I'm wondering if there is a standard way to install python applications with pip (without using sudo) to get it to work globally?

Example:

- I want to install a command line journal application with pip called
  jrnl. It works fine if you do "sudo pip install jrnl", however, I'm
  guessing this is a cringe-worthy way to do it.
- If I install without sudo just using "pip install jrnl" it installs
  in .local/ without global access.

I've found several ways to do it but wondering if there is a common and accepted way to do it that is secure?

Thanks!

Comment: Add that  location to your path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be installed anywhere that is in your path. Several options I found are:

1. Install to `.local` via:

   - `pip install --user <pip-pkg-name>`
   - This will install it in `.local` as you have noted so that location needs to be in your path, using the `.bashrc` file that can be done.
   - Add this `export PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/.local/bin` to your `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file. With that you can reach it from anywhere.
2. Add a custom path for with this line `export PYTHONUSERBASE=/myappenv` in your `.bashrc` file. Now when you do `pip install --user <pip-pkg-name>` it will be installed in `/myappenv`.

   - Note you have to create that path `/myappenv` first and add it to your `.bashrc` file with the line `export PATH=$PATH:/myappenv`
3. Now that being said the so-called standard way you mentioned should be using `python environment a.ka. virtualenv` to install and run packages for that app and not globally as done in (1) and (2) above.

   - Install either for python2+ with `sudo pip install virtualenv`, or for python 3+ with `sudo pip3 install virtualenv`.
   - Usage:

     - `virtualenv venv`
     - Pick an interpreter of your choice with:

       - Python 2+: `virtualenv -p python2.7 venv`
       - Python 3+: `virtualenv -p python3 myenv`
     - Activate it: `source venv/bin/activate`
     - Deactivate it: `deactivate`

See:

http://kazhack.org/?post/2014/12/12/pip-gem-install-without-sudo,

https://gist.github.com/Geoyi/d9fab4f609e9f75941946be45000632b